# Optimisation of RXJS chain

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

There has to be a better way to do this, right?

```ts
const source$ = combineLatest([
    folder$.pipe(
        filter(folder => folder.canBeLoaded()),
    ),
    page$,
    sort$,
]).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onceDestroyed$),
    switchMap(([folder, page, sort]) => combineLatest([
        of(folder),
        of(page),
        of(sort),
        // buffer$: BehaviourSubjhect<number>
        buffer$.pipe(
            startWith(-1),
            pairwise(),
            filter(([buffered, wanted]) => wanted > buffered ),
            map(([, current]) => current),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        ),
    ])),
);
```

`withLatestFrom` comes to my mind, but it will return once per parent, I need `buffer$` to be able to emit multiple times!

Comment: not clear about what you want to do.

Comment: @FanCheung I need to the updated value of buffer every time it gets from lower to higher, or it's current value if any of the other (folder, page, sort) emits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to be that complicated, below should work upper/lower stream are always the latest.

```
const source$ = combineLatest([
    folder$.pipe(
        filter(folder => folder.canBeLoaded()),
    ),
    page$,
    sort$,
]).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onceDestroyed$),
    switchMap(([folder, page, sort]) => 
        buffer$.pipe(
            startWith(-1),
            pairwise(),
            filter(([buffered, wanted]) => wanted > buffered ),
            map(([, current]) => current),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map(current => [folder, page, sort,current]),

        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: The `distinctUntilChanged` won't work unless it is used on the buffer by itself, but I get the point. This should indeed work, thanks.

Comment: Fix the `distinctUntilChanged` and I'll be happy to accept ;)

Comment: only a tiny change. updated the code. It won't fire unless current is different value